# Can a disable person play cricket as others play?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a player is physically different from other players like if he has artificial body parts can he play cricket like others in ICC?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are cricketers who play with prosthetic limbs, for example [Tom Carter](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-south-east-wales-33627406) who plays recreational cricket in Wales. In the near future, I suspect it's very unlikely that an athletes with a prosthetic limb will compete with able bodied athletes at a much higher level than that due to the limitations that even the best prosthetics place on movement and balance.

On the other hand, there are of course various forms of cricket designed for athletes with disabilities, whether they be physical disabilities or mental disabilities; of particular note are [blind cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_cricket) and deaf cricket.